# Binding flag enum to xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I have bitwise enum

```
Public People People
{
  get{return Get<People>(People.None);}
  set{ Set(value);}
}
```

And I can't figured out how to bind it to xaml. We used datagridtextcolumn, and I don't know if it's appropriate

```
<DatagridTextColumn Header="People"
                    Binding="{m: Binding Source={StaticResource People}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Value Converter`](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to this. In the converter you would have to detail how it would obtain the `string` for the `enum` (most likely a `.ToString()` but you may want something more advanced.)

First you would need to add it as a resource for the page

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:EnumToStringConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

You can then add it like this

```
<DatagridTextColumn Header="People"
                    Binding="{m: Binding Source={StaticResource People}
                    Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"
```

Comment: Im using usercontrol instead of windoe so I can't implement the IValueConverter like in the example